# MySQL Workbench Export 6.3.7 doesnt emit a "USE `database`;" statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-backups, database-restore

We regularly get per-table backup files from a remote installation produced by a MySQL Workbench version 6.3.7. All files do not include the Use `database`; statement. This results in an "ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 22: No database selected". This in turn forces us here in this installation to *manually* add such statements to each and every file.

We must do the Per-Table type of BU because we selectively restore only part of the back-upped tables. Therefore, the "Default *target* schema" settings available when choosing "import from a self-contained file" is not available.

Older versions (e.g., 6.2.3) did emit these statements in each of these SQL files.

The situation didn't change even when logged in as 'root' on both the source and the target machine.

We searched the man pages, the web and this forum to find a setting that will do so, to no avail. Can any body help us?

Regards,

Meir

Comment: I'm of the mind they should not include them, and the files can then be used in devops where your target db is something else and set prior to the connection run of the extract. Had they existed inside the file on top of create if not exist and insert, it would create a different problem. No way to satisfy everyone all the time.

Comment: @Drew, you are absolutely right. In fact _my_ application above calls for a different DB, although we gave it the same name to overcome the problem you mentioned. But they could provide the same "Target Data base" field and function to avoid the "No DB selected" error.

Comment: People will never cease to be dissatisfied with the lack of an option especially on free tools where they expect everything for nothing. Up until the point it drops your tables and you lose years of data because you inadvertently accepted some default.